# Random 403 errors in PHP loop

Tags: php, mysql, apache, http-status-code-403

I have some code that cycles through database entries and fills out a template, but after 5 or 6 hours it stops looping and throws a 403 error. 
Here is the code I'm using the pull the data:

```
if(isset($_GET['pageid'])){
     $page_id = $_GET['pageid'];
}else{
     $page_id = 0;
}
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'readonlyuser', 'password');
$query_pageid = "SELECT PAGE_ID FROM database.GENERAL WHERE PAGE_ID > ".$page_id." AND ACTIVE LIMIT 1;";
$query_results = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_pageid);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query_results) != 0){
    $query_fields = mysqli_fetch_array($query_results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $page_id = $query_fields['PAGE_ID'];
}else{
    header("refresh:0;url=http://10.10.10.10/address/index.php");
    exit();
}
```

Have any of you by chance come across something like this?

Comment: Possibly running out of memory, disk space or a time limit of some sort. We'll need more information, such as any error logs.

Comment: Not a single thing in the error log pertaining to that application..

Answer (score 0):

A 403 error means indicates that the server van be reached but refuses to take any further action. Running a loop for 5 - 6 hours will store alot of data and you might be out of memory.

One way you could fix this is by using an api.

Comment: How would you go about doing that?

Comment: There are alot of ways you could make an api which you can easily find. What i recommend if you want to make an api is either using a php framework like Laravel or use Nodejs to make one.

Comment: This would keep you from getting 403 errors from too many requests?

Comment: Yes. Unless you put a limited amount of calls on your api. You can setup your api so that it will only handle 30 request every minute.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking your web server logs, you look like you are basically creating a DoS attack on yourself with a continuous loop of hitting the web server.

Comment: Can't find a single error pertaining to that application or to server requests, only errors for a different application.